# Why doesn't my docker actually log anything?

Tags: logging, docker

I have the following python file:

```
 import time
 from datetime import datetime


 while True:
     time.sleep(1)
     print(datetime.now())
```

I've added it to a Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7


WORKDIR /test
COPY test.py /test/
CMD ["python", "test.py"]
```

If I build this and run with

```
sudo docker run -it --name test myimage
```

everything is awesome. Every second or so it prints the current time.

On the other hand, if I run it with:

```
sudo docker run -d --name test myimage
```

It runs off into the background, but if I do...

```
sudo docker logs test
```

I get nothing! Not a darn thing.

Any clue why this is happening, or how I could figure it out? Both when I'm using `-d` and not when I run `docker inspect` it gives me `"Type": "json-file", "Config": {}`

I'm runing Docker 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a, on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Check if it's IO buffering: https://stackoverflow.com/q/107705/596285

Comment: @BMitch that was it, thanks! I spent a couple of hours last night fighting this darn thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a tty attached, python is likely buffering stdout. There are [lots of ways to solve this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/107717/596285), including adding this change to your script:

```
print(datetime.now(), flush=True)
```

Or without changing your script, you can run `stdbuf` to turn off output buffering:

```
CMD ["stdbuf", "-oL", "python", "test.py"]
```

Comment: Because I was using another command (i.e. `waitress-serve` in my case), so I added `ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED definitely` to my Dockerfile (it could be any non-empty string, FWIW)